# How could I estimate slope of lines on a scatter plot?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, regression, machine-learning-model

I have a list of coordinate pairs. To the human eye, they form lines with a constant slope:

[image]

This is how I generated that image above:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(42)

slope = 1.2 # all lines have the same slope

offsets = np.arange(10) # we will have 10 lines, each with different y-intercept
xslist=[]
yslist=[]

for offset in offsets:
    # each line will be described by a variable number of points:
    size = np.random.randint(low=50,high=100)

     # eachline starts from somewhere -5 and -2 and ends between 2 and 5
    xs = np.random.uniform(low=np.random.uniform(-5,-2), high=np.random.uniform(2,5),size=size)

     # add some random offset and some random noise
    ys = slope * xs + offset + np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=0.1, size=1) + np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=0.01, size=size)
    xslist.append(xs)
    yslist.append(ys)

# bring all x and y points together to single arrays
xs = np.concatenate(xslist) # xs: array([-0.37261674,  0.58267626, -3.72592914 ...
ys = np.concatenate(yslist) # ys: array([-0.53638699,  0.61729781, -4.52132114, 

# plot results
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.scatter(xs,ys)
```

I can generate lots of `xs` and `ys`. In my real world scenario, I won't know which point belongs to which line, so cannot simply separate the points to different groups and just apply least squares fitting to each group.

**How could I, using machine learning or otherwise, build a function which takes `xs` and `ys` as input, and returns a slope estimate of the lines on an image like above?**

---

### Why simple least squares fitting doesn't seem to work

Let's generate new data where the failure of least squares fitting is more obvious. Let's have a slope of 2.4 and y-intercepts between 0 and a few hundred.

Data generation:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(42)

slope = 2.4

offsets = np.arange(0,500,100)
xslist=[]
yslist=[]

for offset in offsets:

    size = np.random.randint(low=50,high=100)

    xs = np.random.uniform(low=np.random.uniform(-5,-2), high=np.random.uniform(2,5),size=size)
    ys = slope * xs + offset + np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=0.1, size=1) + np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=0.01, size=size)

    xslist.append(xs)
    yslist.append(ys)

xs = np.concatenate(xslist)
ys = np.concatenate(yslist)
```

Least squares fitting of a line using [`np.polyfit()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html):

```
a, b = np.polyfit(xs, ys, deg=1)
```

Note that I cannot fit to just one line, as I don't know which points belong to one line.

Plot results:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
plt.scatter(xs,ys)

line_x = np.arange(-5,5,0.01)
line_y = a*line_x + b
plt.plot(line_x,line_y,c='r',linewidth=10)

plt.gca().set_aspect(1/8)
```

ie:

[image]

The obtained slope using least squares fitting (ie the slope of the red line) is very much different than the slope of the lines formed by black dots. (Note that the scale is different on the x and y axis.)

Printing both `a` (our slope estamate) and the real slope `slope`:

```
print(a)
print(slope)
```

get:

```
4.295790412452058
2.4
```

This error is too much for my real world application.

---

### Function to generate mock data

As requested in the comments, here is a function to generate data similar to the above examples:

```
def get_data(number_of_examples):

    np.random.seed(42)

    list_of_xs = []
    list_of_ys = []
    true_slopes = []

    for _ in range(number_of_examples):

        slope = np.random.uniform(low=-10, high=10)

        offsets = np.arange(0,
                            np.random.randint(low=20, high=200),
                            np.random.randint(low=1, high=10))
        xslist=[]
        yslist=[]

        for offset in offsets:

            size = np.random.randint(low=np.random.randint(low=40, high=60),
                                     high=np.random.randint(low=80, high=100))

            xs = np.random.uniform(low=np.random.uniform(-5,-2),
                                   high=np.random.uniform(2,5),size=size)
            ys = slope * xs + offset + \
                np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=0.1, size=1) + \
                np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=0.01, size=size)

            xslist.append(xs)
            yslist.append(ys)

        xs = np.concatenate(xslist)
        ys = np.concatenate(yslist)

        list_of_xs.append(xs)
        list_of_ys.append(ys)
        true_slopes.append(slope)
    
    return list_of_xs, list_of_ys, true_slopes
```

Try it, get 10 examples:

```
list_of_xs, list_of_ys, true_slopes = data = get_data(10)
```

Plot results (the slope of the red line is what I am trying to predict using the coordinates of the blue dots):

```
for xs, ys, true_slope in zip(list_of_xs, list_of_ys, true_slopes):
    plt.figure()
    plt.scatter(xs, ys)
    plt.plot(xs, xs*true_slope, c='r')
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

and so on.

Comment: Do the lines even have different slopes? From the picture, the slopes all look the same.

Comment: see [least squares fitting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares#Problem_statement)

Comment: You can use sklearn linear regression http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_ols.html (assuming you want to apply it to other datasets,  since the slope of those lines could simple be (y-y')/(x-x') for any pair. You do not even need to think of machine kearning for this simple problem (at least this toy case)

Comment: @Dave yes, all lines have the same slope.

Comment: @NikosM. that would be applicable if I had only one line, but I have multiple lines (and I don't know in advance which is which).

Comment: @GermanCM thank you for the link. I fail to see how I could apply the technique described there, as I have points from multiple lines with the same slope, not just one line.

Comment: A classical method to solve this is the Hough transform.

Comment: Then cluster the data in classes representing different lines. The criterion for two points to be in the same class (line) is if they are colinear (search for colinearity criterion). Then apply least squares fitting to each class.

Comment: In the simulation, you could group the lines by their intercepts. Is there some characteristic that the points in each line have that uniquely identifies them as belonging to that group? An example might be if the ten intercepts correspond to a control group and nine different treatments.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The procedure that you can use is the following. First cluster your data with gaussian mixture models. This method should also work with multiple lines with different slopes. It should be able to deal with intersections as points near an intersection can belong to both clusters and a wrong classification will not lead to huge differences in the results of the regression.

I will post the complete code.

```
# Your code for generating the data
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(42)
slope = 2.4

offsets = np.arange(0,500,100)
xslist=[]
yslist=[]

for offset in offsets:

    size = np.random.randint(low=50,high=100)

    xs = np.random.uniform(low=np.random.uniform(-5,-2), high=np.random.uniform(2,5),size=size)
    ys = slope * xs + offset + np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=0.1, size=1) + np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=0.01, size=size)

    xslist.append(xs)
    yslist.append(ys)

xs = np.concatenate(xslist)
ys = np.concatenate(yslist)
```

We will use your data points to generate multiple gaussian mixture models. We will fix the number of components by using the number of components with the minimal value of the Bayesian Information Criterion (BIC).

```
# Create multiple Gaussian Mixture models
from sklearn.mixture import GaussianMixture
X = np.vstack((xs, ys)).T
n_components = np.arange(1, 21)
models = [GaussianMixture(n, covariance_type='full', random_state=0).fit(X) for n in n_components]

# Get optimal number of components by using the index of the components with the minimal value for the Bayesian Information Criterion (BIC)
n_components_optimal = np.argmin(np.array([model.bic(X) for model in models])) + 1
```

Plot the results and see how well the clustering with the optimal number of clusters works.

```
# Code for plotting
gaussian_mixture_model_optimal = GaussianMixture(n_components_optimal, covariance_type='full', random_state=0).fit(X)
labels = gaussian_mixture_model_optimal.predict(X)
plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], c=labels, s=40, cmap='viridis')
```

[image]

Now, use the clustered data and create subdataframes from them and fit your linear regressions.

```
import pandas as pd 
    
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "x": xs,
    "y": ys,
    "cluster": labels,
})

# 
cluster_number = 1
X_sub = df.query('cluster == @cluster_number').values
```

Comment: Good point on clustering with GMMs,  but BIC as a way to automatically determine the number of classes can be misleading. I would leave this option open.

Comment: The problem with AIC is that the optimal number of clusters is more difficult to dertermine. But you are right that one should evaluate how well the given metric performs and then adapt the approach.

Comment: @MachineLearner thank you for the great answer. I'll leave this question open for a bit more (as some in the comments on the question planned to answer it too) and if this turns out to be the best option, will accept it. Nevertheless, this is an answer to learn from.